# Cookies. Case Sensitive Paths. How to rewrite URLs

Tags: asp.net, iis-6

We have a sizable collection of applications (>50) all running under a single domain but with different virtual directories. Pretty standard stuff. We store cookies using paths to segregate cookies by application. Paths are set the the Application Path.

This seems to work fine as long as the casing of the URL is the same as the application path. If it is different, the browser fails to retrieve the collection of cookies.

Is there any very basic way (ISAPI? Global ASAX?) to rewrite all URLs so that they match the Application Path? Ideally this is something that can be configured at the application level.

Currently stuck on IIS6.

thanks

Comment: May be dumb question, but why aren't they matching already?...can you give me an example of a url that isn't matching your app paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wondering if this is a possible (even a good) solution:

In Global.asax:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
    string application = HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;

    if (!url.StartsWith(application))
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(application + url.Substring(application.Length));
    }
}
```

Comment: Definately the solution to our issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative URLs in conjunction with a [BASE](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) tag might work?